# Blender 2.9 Mantaflow - fluid weird behavior

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am receiving very strange results with Blender 2.9 fluid simulation - even though I am only trying to achieve an effect of the cup falling on the side, the fluid flows in the air unnaturally, and too quickly. Can you help me figure out what I am missing? I'm already trying to figure it out second day in the row, have checked all possible guides on Mantaflow, and searched many pages looking for the answer without any success. I'd be really grateful for someone to point out where I am making a mistake.

Please consider I need this exact scale to be applied (as my scene is being created in regards to real dimensions).

Feel free to check the .[blend file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMwIb.gif) here.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: I am facing a wall on the way through the 3-month long project. I would sincerely appreciate any advice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After a third day of experimenting with the settings, i've found that the "effector" object thickness has to be increased to prevent too fast collission with the fluid. Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The "effector" object thickness has to be increased to prevent too fast collission with the fluid.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on how to do this? Perhaps add an image showing where in the UI